How to have external logins in ASP.NET MVC not need email confirmation, but still keep normal registration need one?
I have an ASP.NET MVC app with identity and I have Google and Facebook external logins which work as intended with email confirmation. But if I have it set to no email confirmation, then it just doesn't need email confirmation for the normal registration either. What is the approach?
I tried setting the emailConfirmed to the user in the external login code to true but it doesn't work and I can't get myself to figure out how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated <3
I tried getting rid of the external login redirect logic to the email confirmation but all that does is that it logs in normally, but if u sign out and try login with the same external login, it makes u register again and not just log you in. I'm guessing it's because the program.cs is looking for EmailConfirmation to be set to true for each user.
